# OS Utilities vs Java API's for text search in a file

Tags: java

Suppose i want to search some text in a file. I want to know when we should use system utilities/programs like grep and when we should use Java API's like reading a line, and then search the text in that line or use java Scanner class.

I want to understand the trade-offs between the two approaches. I mean, suppose if we use grep, then will there be communication overhead between JVM and the grep process? Is creation of a new OS process for grep an overhead?

Does grep performs better than normal java file search?

Please help...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there will be an overhead. Starting an external process and communicating with it is costly. And moreover, many systems don't have a grep command. If you want to make your Java code portable, don't rely on OS-specific commands.

Another problem is that OS commands will be able to search (for example) in files, but not in your in-memory data structures.

Comment: Isn't JVM communicating with OS when asking for a file pointer? I mean, some communication is happening even when we manipulate files through Java. How is it different from communication with other process?

Comment: There is a difference between calling a function of a native library of the OS and starting a new process and communicating with this process through IO. But you're right: every native call has a cost. That's one of the reasons why most of the Java library is implemented in Java.

Comment: Let's keep aside the portability of the program for a moment. Let's assume a program will always be run on a single OS. Now, suppose I have a 1 GB text file and I want to count the occurences of the word "apple" in this text file. I write 2 programs where in one program I do it through grep utility and in another, through Java's Scanner class. Which program do you think will perform better?

Comment: It all depends on the implementation of the program. I wouldn't use Scanner for this. And of course, the larger the file is, the more negligible it becomes to start a new process. Test it, measure, and choose the solution that you find the best one.

Comment: So, would you prefer grep in this case or you have some other way of doing this? I might be asking silly questions, but it is important for me to understand the difference and trade-offs between the two..

Comment: No, I wouldn't, because portability is important for me. Test both solutions, and choose the right one for YOU.

Comment: I am not trying to solve the problem of searching here..I just wanted to know the trade-offs between system utilities and Java API's in terms of pure performance...To put it in simple words, given a huge file, should grep be considered or would Java API's always win the race?

Answer (score 0):

You're basically trading off system independence for the perceived gain of the tool, in some cases this can't be avoid.

Not every system will have the tools you want installed, in the locations you think they should be or the version you need.

Even if you can deploy the tools with your application, you will need to provide an implementation for each of your targeted platforms.

Sure, it's easy to say "it will never be run on X", but can never come around real quick ;)

There is also the added over head of executing and managing the IO of the external applications, while not difficult, it's much more complex that a well written Java API.

As I said, sometimes, you simply don't have a choice (I have some media inspection tools that I use on Windows and Mac that I'm not about to try and implement in Java, not because it can't be, but because it's complex and time consuming and somebody has already done it (with a native program)).

You need to balance the choice over what the benefits are of the external command weight against the issues of using it.  You should also investigate if a API has already begin developed that might solve  the problem at hand.

IMHO